# How to proxy all unrecognized URLs through to proxy server (including paths under rootURL)

Tags: ember.js

I have an Ember application with rootURL set as /a/b. The Ember application should handle routes /a/b/1 and /a/b/2, and should relay to the proxy server routes /a/b/3 and /a/b/4.

By default, I get UnrecognizedURL errors from /a/b/3 and /a/b/4. Routes such as /a/1 or /b/1 are proxied to server.

Thank you for any insight.

Comment: Are you using EmberData? If so all you need to do is to create an adapter for each resource.

Comment: It is not an issue with AJAX calls, but with the primary page URL routing.

Comment: If that is the case, you can redirect your route to the desired place using callback function inside `route`. For example, `beforeModel` hook